# Java Swing game lags over time

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm making a game with Java Swing and I've realized that after the game as been running for a while, 10 minutes or so, the graphics start lagging a lot. The game loop reports to be running at a constant FPS.

Right now I have it so that repaint is also called once the game loop fires. If I don't sync the graphics, it is so slow different parts being drawn is is visible on the screen. Task manager shows the memory it uses is pretty much the same, however CPU usage gradually increases over time. If I had to guess it would have to be that I'm not using Swing to draw correctly.

The process I currently use for drawing is something like this:

- cast graphics2D object
- super paints graphics object
- Every object draws their graphic using that graphics object.
- Toolkit sync
- Dispose graphics

The panel is `setDoubleBuffered(true)`.

Any idea as to what might be wrong?

EDIT:

I couldn't get my SSCCE to lag, so I went back and retested each draw function, and it turns out

```
    int ilen = drawActorQueue.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < ilen; i++)
    {
        GameActor oo = drawActorQueue.get(i);
        oo.draw(g2d, viewX, viewY);
    }
```

seems to be causing the problem.

I think its because drawActorQueue actually contains pointers to 2 types of objects and GameActor is just the base class.

Does this look to be the case?
I think I can fix it by either using interfaces, or having the list instead point towards the specific arrays for the 2 children objects.

EDIT:
!@#$%^
It was just me being incredibly stupid and not clearing a list. I'll never code or debug when I'm dead tired again.

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for `FileIO`, `XxxStream` or `JDBC`

Comment: Agree with @mKorbel that an SSCCE is the way to go here, but note *"Create graphics object"*  seems suspicious to me.  If doing custom painting in a component, you would normally be given a `Graphics` object to work with.  That graphics instance should not be disposed in your own code.  *"The panel is `setDoubleBuffered(true)`."*  That is the default for a `JPanel`.

Comment: Yeah I meant the graphics object in the parameter.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE, before that read Oracle tutorial about Painting in Swing and search here on this forum

Comment: Other suppositions (that's pretty much all you will get until you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)): an infinite loop (like calling repaint() constantly, or invoking repaint() in paint()) or Timer with a too small delay.

Comment: I'll make a SSCCE tomorrow.My brain is dead tonight

Comment: Also check for swallowed exceptions; the EDT will restart automatically, but the damage may be pervasive.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your app is not leaking memory and GC'ing heavily.  Run the program with verbose GC logging on to see if it an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a profiler to your application.

For example, `visualvm`. Any hotspot should turn up quickly with "sampling".

What is really nice about visualvm is that you can actually attach when the problem is really happening, but run at full speed before it happens.

It will also show you charts of the memory consumption and GC activity. If you see your application churn through a lot of memory in a short time, you may want to see if you can reduce that.

`visualvm` is a super powerful, free tool for Java that should be in everybodys toolbox, and the first place to go to when you see performance issues.